# Binding UserControl properties within DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to bind `UserControl` properties within a `DataGrid` row. My XAML is as below.
I have `DirectionArrow` control which shows different angles in each row. How can I bind this to angle property `DataGrid` `ItemsSource` property?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DtgProfiles" Grid.Row="0"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding Project.SelectedAxis.Profiles}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="No" Width="4*" Binding="{Binding Path=ProfileOrder,Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Direction" Width="8*" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:DirectionArrow
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="13" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="13" BackgroundFill="LightBlue"
                        LineAngle="{Binding Direction}" LineLength="1"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: `LineAngle="{Binding Direction}"` should work, provided you did not make the common mistake to explicitly assign the UserControl's DataContext - either to itself, or to a private view model.

Comment: The code you showed is not enough to answer.
Add description details: an implementation of the collection items `Project.SelectedAxis.Profiles` (only property declarations are sufficient) and an implementation of `controls:DirectionArrow` (property LineAngle and setting DataContext, If any)

Comment: I  resolved this by adding the property directly to the class instead of vM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  resolved this by adding the property directly to the class instead of vM